# change default save-as type in excel

Tags: excel, save

I have a macro template file. It shows save as dialog box with ".xls" format as default. I want to show the default type as ".xlsm". I need to do it using vba.

Please anyone help me in solving this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: *I need to do using vba* - please add the `vba` or `excel-vba` tag and also **show the code you have tried to accomplish this** and where it is failing.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your valuable time. Next time, I'll post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following code. It works for me!!

```
Dim FileSaveAsName As Variant, intchoice As Integer
Static saveProcess As Boolean 

If Not saveProcess Then 
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If SaveAsUI = True Then 'Save As... was selected
        saveProcess = True 
        Set FileSaveName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

        FileSaveName.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
        FileSaveName.FilterIndex = 2   'select to save with a ".xlsm" extension
        intchoice = FileSaveName.Show
        If intchoice <> 0 Then
            FileSaveName.Execute
        End If
        Cancel = True
    Else 'Normal Save 
        saveProcess = True 
        Cancel = True
        ThisWorkbook.Save 
    End If
    saveProcess = False 
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.