# Creating a Command Button in Word to Save As but the file format must be Macros-Enabled

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image]

I have little coding experience and I've trawled through these forums but can't find an answer specifically for Microsoft Word.

I've created two command buttons where the first requires the user to click and it enables them to Save As the form, then they will click the next button to 'Click to Send' which I've done the code easily for the 'Click to Send'.
The problem is with the Save As button is that I cannot get it to automatically change the default Save As type to "Word Macro-Enabled Document" as it currently keeps just defaulting to "Word Document"

I know there's ways of adding multiple functions to one click command buttons but I really want these separate for now. The current code I'm using for the Save As button is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show

End Sub
```

Any help will be immensely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926915/change-default-save-as-type-in-excel)

Comment: Record a macro and look at the code

Comment: Hi guys and thank you for the answers so far. The similar questions that are linked don't readily make sense to me and I can't get them to work in my Word document, as they are for Excel. Recording the macros doesn't yield anything either as all I literally want the coding to do is make the default file saving type as "Word Macro-Enabled Document (*.docx)" rather than just "Word Document". Does that make sense?

Comment: Use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58641468/62576), and the enumerations from [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat). Combining the two will answer your question.

Comment: Hi Ken, your answer is closest so far but it's still telling me that it needs an object and I don't understand what an object is in regards to it. so the code I've currently got (that isn't working) is: 

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
docx.SaveAs2 (newfilename = MSWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatTemplate)
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prompt the SaveAs File dialog with `.docm` as the default file type:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .FilterIndex = 2 '.docm file format
        .Show
        
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            ThisDocument.SaveAs2 .SelectedItems(1), wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Raymond Wu - You are a wonderful glorious legend and you have saved me so much time on this Friday. Thank you very very much! <3

Comment: @Shelley - I just noticed there's an unnecessary line - `Set saveDialog = nothing` at the end, please delete it. I have edited the answer.